# Can I use tuples with AnyObject?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, tuples

I'm wondering if I can do something like this:

```
override func someCocoaFunc(someParameter:AnyObject?) {
    if let parameter = someParameter as! Tuple {
        let parameterType = parameter.1
        if parameterType == "Heads up, this is an Int" {
            print(parameter.0 + 1) //prints 2
        }
        else {
             //fallback
        }
    }
}
let myTuple = (1,"Heads up, this is an Int")
someCocoaFunc(myTuple)
```

Obviously this doesn't work because Tuple is not a class, or at least not one I can cast to anyway. Is there a way to get this to work, if so how? If not, what is the best way to determine the type of an `AnyObject`? I tried:

```
if parameter is Bool {
//some code
}
else if parameter is Int {
//some code
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I think because Bool is just a typealias'd Int or something? So to summarize, can I use Tuples here, and if not, what should I do? To add some context, I'm writing one class that is used in serval different targets, so I can't be sure what the value will be, just that it is either an Int or Bool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use tuples here because they are compound types and therefore no classes.

The problem with the `if` is that for compatibility `Bool` and `Int` get converted to `NSNumber` that has a `boolValue` and `integerValue` property which gets called if you cast them. So 0 and 1 is equivalent to `true` and `false` and therefore ambiguous.

As solution I would suggest to make a class which holds both values as `Optionals`:

```
class Holder {
    let boolValue: Bool?
    let intValue: Int?
}
```